# How correctly call startActivityForResult from sub child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am working on an android app with kotlin, so...

context:
i have an activity(A) than have a viewPager, the viewPager holds 2 fragments(F1,F2) one of this fragments(F1) have another 2 fragment(CF1,CF2)

**The problem** is when i call an activity(B) forResult from fragment(CF1) the activity(A) receive the result from activity(B), then is passed to fragment(F1), but never receive on fragment(CF1)

```
val intent = Intent(activity, B::class.java)//how i call activity(B) so good
            intent.putExtra("select",1)
            //parentFragment!!.startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE)//
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE)

//how i receive on Activity(A) so good
    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
            for(i in 0..adapterNormal.COUNT){
                var f = adapterNormal.getItem(i)
                f?.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)
            }
    }

    //how i receive on fragment(F1) so good
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    cli_name = data!!.getStringExtra("clie_name")
                    cli_id = data.getStringExtra("clie_id")
                }
        }
//how i tried to receive on fragment(CF1)
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "requestCode = $requestCode")
    }
```

I tried to simplify the problem, I hope anybody can help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling CF1's onActivityResult function.

Calling super.onActivityResult is enough to route the call from an Activity to a Fragment, but not to route it to a nested Fragment (which is this case).

So, you should make that call explicitly:

Fragment F1:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        cli_name = data!!.getStringExtra("clie_name")
        cli_id = data.getStringExtra("clie_id")
    }
    cf1?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when i call an activity(B) forResult from fragment(CF1) the activity(A) receive the result from activity(B), then is passed to fragment(F1), but never receive on fragment(CF1)

In your fragment (CF1) use startActivityForResult

```
        val intent = Intent(context, B::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("select",1)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE)
```

Don't Implement `onActivityResult` in your activity, also implement that in your fragment(CF1) only

```
        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_CODE -> when (resultCode) {
                RESULT_OK -> {
                    //do your work here
                }
              }
            }
        }
```

This is working perfectly in my project.

And don't forget to call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)` in your **Activity(B)**